# why I cant access a public method from a class? (java)

Tags: java, android

I have the following method in  MapViewActivity.java

```
 public void startMapEditActivity() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MapViewActivity.this, MapEditActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE_FLOOR, mSelectedMap);
        startActivity(intent); // start map edit mode
    }
```

I'm trying to access the method from MapActivity.java as:

```
startMapEditActivity();
```

but it doesn't work that way it throws the following message:

```
The method startMapEditActivity() is undefined for the type MapActivity
```

Comment: Well it's in MapViewActivity, so you need to call it *on* a MapViewActivity...

Comment: What are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: @KamleshArya still will fail because of MapViewActivity.this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your usage to a static method with a parameter of [context](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html) and pass whatever mSelectedMap is too, this way you can use this one method in your entire app to start this activity by passing in a valid [context](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html) (like an [activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)) and the info that is represented by `mSelectedMap`:

```
static public void startMapEditActivity(final Context context, boolean mSelectedMap) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, MapEditActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE_FLOOR, mSelectedMap);
    startActivity(intent); // start map edit mode
}
```

Example Usage (from a view clicklistener):

```
    setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            MapEditActivity.startMapEditActivity(view.getContext(), aSelectedMapObject);
        }
    }));
```

Example usage from some method in MapViewActivity:

```
  private void gotoMapEditActivity(){
      MapEditActivity.startMapEditActivity(MapViewActivity.this, aSelectedMapObject);
  }
```

Comment: tried your code and this is what I receive: The method putExtra(String, boolean) in the type Intent is not applicable for the arguments (String, Object)

Comment: WHat is the type of mSelectedMap?  (You never stated)

Comment: you can change the param `, Object mSelectedMap` to `, boolean mSelectedMap)` if it is a boolean etc...

Comment: ok...so it is a boolean,  check the edit `static public void  startMapEditActivity(final Context context, boolean mSelectedMap) {`

Answer (score 0):

That method doesn't belong to `MapActivity`, it belongs to `MapViewActivity`.  You can't call it from outside `MapViewActivity`.

The easiest way to solve your problem would be to copy the method `startMapEditActivity` into the class `MapActivity`.  This way `MapActivity` has it's own version of `startMapEditActivity` that you can use from within that class.